# git not ignoring folder specified by .gitignore

Tags: xcode, git, gitignore

I am using [the .gitignore file from here](http://goo.gl/vyNoNl) but I still am still finding that

```
 CalFoo.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/wcochran.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate
```

is staged for a commit?

Why isn't the folder `xcuserdata` excluded?

Comment: Did you added the `.gitignore` when that file was already tracked by `git`?

Answer (score 4):

Did you already  commit after adding .gitignore to tracking files?

```
git rm -r --cached .

git add .

git commit -m ".gitignore is now should working"
```

Comment: Yes, I committed the .gitignore file. When I do something benign in Xcode (e.g., just view an iOS storyboard) this changed Xcode's state and git thinks there are changes to commit. I want git to ignore this. BTW, thanks for answering.